# Network Message not sending, Attempt to send to not connected connection {1}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

This appears to be an order of operations issue perhaps but I'm not sure where I'm putting things out of order. I'm trying to send a message from the client on a button press to the server that consists of the clients name:

```
string msg = "TELLCLIENTNAME|" + playerName;
SendMsg(msg, reliableChannelID);
```

On the server script I have a case

```
case "TELLCLIENTNAME":
    OnTellClientName(splitData[1], recConnectionID);
    break;
```

to look for the string and once this gets received I'm just wanting to send confirmation to the screen via text feedback:

```
void OnTellClientName(string playerName, int cnnID) {
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player Name : " + playerName + " on Connection ID : " + cnnID + "\n";}
```

Simple enough but I'm not getting things working, the error I'm getting is:

```
Attempt to send to not connected connection {1}
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkTransport:Send(Int32, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32, Byte&)
Client:SendMsg(String, Int32) (at Assets/_Scripts/Networking/Client.cs:96)
Client:Connect() (at Assets/_Scripts/Networking/Client.cs:90)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Client.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Loader load;
    public GameObject player;

    private int ourClientID;
    private int connectionID;

    private const int maxConnections = 100;

    private int port = 5708;

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    public int reliableChannelID { get; set; }
    public int reliableSeqChannelID { get; set; }
    public int unreliableSeqChannelID { get; set; }

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    public string playerName { get; set; }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;

        Debug.Log("Client is connected to server.");

        int recHostID;
        int recConnectionID;
        int recChannelID;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recNetworkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostID, out recConnectionID, out recChannelID, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recNetworkEvent)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0])
                {
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid message : " + msg);
                        break;
                }
                break;

                Debug.Log("Receiving : " + msg);
        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        Instantiate(player);

        playerName = GameManager.playerID;

        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig config = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        unreliableSeqChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(config, maxConnections);

        //hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);
        connectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostID, load.clientIPList[0], port, 0, out error);

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;

        string msg = "TELLCLIENTNAME|" + playerName;
        SendMsg(msg, reliableChannelID);
    }

    public void SendMsg(string m, int channelID)
    {
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(m);    // Convert string into byte array
        NetworkTransport.Send(hostID, connectionID, channelID, msg, msg.Length * sizeof(char), out error);

        Debug.Log("Error : " + error.ToString());

        Debug.Log("Sending : " + m);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Disconnect(hostID, connectionID, out error);
    }
}
```

Server.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ServerClient : MessageBase
{
    public int connectionID;
    public string playerName;
    public string animalType;
    public byte[] playerTexBytes;
}

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();

    private int connectionID;
    private const int maxConnections = 100;

    private int port = 5708;

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    public int reliableChannelID { get; set; }
    public int reliableSeqChannelID { get; set; }
    public int unreliableSeqChannelID { get; set; }

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    public GameObject playerObject;
    public Dictionary<int, GameObject> players = new Dictionary<int, GameObject>();

    GameObject infoDisplayText;
    GameObject networkTitle;
    string networkMsg;

    private void Awake()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        networkTitle = GameObject.Find("NetworkTitle");
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig config = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        unreliableSeqChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(config, maxConnections);

        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
        webHostID = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, port, null);

        isStarted = true;

        //DEBUG
        networkTitle.GetComponent<Text>().text = "HOST";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Host Started, IP : " + Network.player.ipAddress + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Socket open, Host ID is " + hostID + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "My player name is " + GameManager.playerID + "\n";

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostID;
        int recConnectionID;
        int recChannelID;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recNetworkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostID, out recConnectionID, out recChannelID, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recNetworkEvent)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                OnConnection(recConnectionID);
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:

                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0])
                {
                    case "TELLCLIENTNAME":
                        OnTellClientName(splitData[1], recConnectionID);
                        break;

                    case "PLAYERDATA":
                        OnPlayerData(splitData[1], splitData[2], recConnectionID);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid message : " + msg);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                OnDisconnection(recConnectionID);
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnConnection(int cnnID)
    {
        // DEBUG
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + cnnID + " has connected.\n";

    }

    void SendMsg(string message, int channelID, int cnnID)
    {
        List<ServerClient> c = new List<ServerClient>();
        c.Add(clients.Find(x => x.connectionID == cnnID));
        SendMsg(message, channelID, c);
    }

    void SendMsg(string message, int channelID, List<ServerClient> c) // Overload method
    {
        // DEBUG
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Sending : " + message + "\n";

        // Convert string into byte array
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

        foreach (ServerClient sc in c)
        {
            NetworkTransport.Send(hostID, sc.connectionID, channelID, msg, msg.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
        }
    }

    void OnTellClientName(string playerName, int cnnID)
    {
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player Name : " + playerName + " on Connection ID : " + cnnID + "\n";
    }

    void OnPlayerData(string playerName, string animalType, int cnnID)
    {
        // DEBUG
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player Name : " + playerName + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Animal Type : " + animalType + "\n";
    }

    void OnDisconnection(int recConnectionID)
    {
        // DEBUG
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + recConnectionID + " has disconnected.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: After your call to `NetworkTransport.Connect()`, you aren't checking the `error` variable.  Try casting the `byte` to a [`Networking.NetworkError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkError.html) object and make sure it evaluates to `Networking.NetworkError.Ok`.

Comment: @Foggzie When I `Debug.Log("Error : " + error.ToString());` I get Error : 2. Where can I find the error code description for this?

Comment: @Foggzie I think I just found the code. Am I correct in thinking that error 2 = WrongConnection? If so where am I connecting incorrectly in my client script?

Comment: It looks like your server script is using the `port` variable and your client script is using `0` as the port parameter of `NetworkTransport.AddHost`.  Also, you can cast the `error` to ensure that 2 means WrongConnection: `Debug.Log("Error : " + (error as Networking.NetworkError).ToString());`

Comment: @Foggzie Do you know why I'd be getting the error `The type or namespace 'Networking' could not be found` even though I'm `using UnityEngine.Networking;`?

Comment: I set both client and server to the same port and I'm still getting the same error. I'm completely lost.